# How to add new variable to footer.tpl opencart?(multi-lang)

Tags: php, html, opencart

Hell,
I tried to echo new Varible to opencart footer.tpl at my template but fail.
I did the following:
1.insert text_facebook into catalog/controller/common/footer.php after:

```
$this->data['text_newsletter'] = $this->language->get('text_newsletter');
```

like this:

```
$this->data['text_facebook']  = $this->language->get('facebook');
```

and added same line for Arabic lang.

2.Added the the:

```
$_['text_facebook']  = 'facebook';
```

before end of file:

```
/catalog/language/english/common/footer.php
```

3.print out put to user like this:

```
<li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/muhamedauda"><?php echo $text_facebook; ?></a> <span class="facebook-icon"></span> </li>
```

I get only : facebook 
echoed to user(web page). 
how can i echo text i defined it into language file?

thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

`$this->data['text_facebook']  = $this->language->get('text_facebook');`

and don't forget to add 
`$_['text_facebook']  = 'facebook';` to all of your languages you use

Comment: Adding to all languages isn't actually required, though recommended if you want to translate it. The only language you are required to add it to is the English language file

Comment: @JayGilford he wrote `multi-lang` in question title so i thought its worth mentioning :)

Comment: Thanks @Chetan Paliwal .... its perfect, I wounder how i forget this ... thank you tooo